# App is broken after 0.9.4 update: undefined is not a function in dynamic_template.js:371

Tags: meteor, meteor-0.9.4

I had a meteor 0.9.3 app that was working.

I ran `meteor update`. Now I have a bunch or errors (60 total):

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function dynamic_template.js:371
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined helpers.js:140
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function router.js:61
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined iron-router-progress.js?2b52a697e5a2fba4ec827721c08cfdd0a5bae508:25
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined global-imports.js?a26cc176b56b3d2b1df619ec7af99630b0fb6a1f:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.about.js?3ead3e2cab8a60252235e31f2533c2179f736294:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.register.js?60e4180bd0193951fab290d41493f5036f66240d:2
... 53 more errors: 
... mainly "Template is not defined" and "Meteor is not defined"
```

Line 371 of dynamic_template.js is the following:

```
UI.registerHelper('DynamicTemplate', Template.__create__('DynamicTemplateHelper', function () {
```

What's wierd is that if I try to go back with `meteor update --release 0.9.3` or `0.9.2`, I still have those errors. So I'm stuck, I have to fix those.

Another anoying thing is that everytime I start my meteor server, I get `updating package catalog` with a progress bar, and my server takes a while (~10s) to start up.

Any ideas?

Comment: you might be using outdated packages

Comment: i think the _updating package catalog progress bar_ issue will be solved with 1.0.0 [see HISTORY.md for upcoming 1.0.0](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v10)... you could test it out by running meteor with a release candidate `$ meteor --release 1.0-rc.2`

Answer (score 0):

In `0.9.4` there are changes to the templating API. See [HISTORY.md on gihub/meteor/meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#api-changes) for more details.

The fix for your immediate problem is to replace `UI` with `Template`

```
Template.registerHelper('DynamicTemplate', Template.__create__('DynamicTemplateHelper', function () {
```